# Writing pandas dataframe to inlfluxdb with a time column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, influxdb

I am creating a dataframe from list with header row as

```
headers = ["InstanceTag", "AnyVendorColtInterfaceTrafficRatioIN", "AnyVendorColtInterfaceTrafficRatioOUT", "AnyVendorColtInterfaceValidPolls", "Service", "CircuitID", "CountryCode", "UsageIdentifier", "Customer", "SubInterfaceDescription", "GMTTimeStamp", "LocalTimeStamp", "tz"]
    OutDf = pd.DataFrame(OutList, columns=headers)
```

Then, I am converting "LocalTimeStamp" field to pandas datetime and setting it as dataframe index.

```
    OutDf['LocalTimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(OutDf['LocalTimeStamp'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ', infer_datetime_format=True)
    OutDf.set_index('LocalTimeStamp', inplace=True)
```

Now, when I try to insert it into influxdb, it fails !

Data in LocalTimeStamp is like "2020-02-17 05:20:00"

```
       client = influxdb.DataFrameClient(host=dbhost, port=dbport, database=dbname, username=username, password=password)
       print(client.write_points(OutDf, 'ubbdata', protocol=u'line', time_precision='s'))
```

**Error:**

```
  File "./pyubb.py", line 116, in <module>
    print(client.write_points(OutDf, 'ubbdata', protocol=u'line', time_precision='s'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/influxdb/_dataframe_client.py", line 138, in write_points
    protocol=protocol)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 530, in write_points
    consistency=consistency)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 598, in _write_points
    protocol=protocol
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 343, in write
    headers=headers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 302, in request
    raise InfluxDBClientError(response.content, response.status_code)
influxdb.exceptions.InfluxDBClientError: 400: {"error":"unable to parse 'ubbdata InstanceTag=\"myrouter_PW-Ether4.2_P_PQR/ABC/IA-000000\",AnyVendorColtInterfaceTrafficRatioIN=8430.693333333333,AnyVendorColtInterfaceTrafficRatioOUT=10866.32,AnyVendorColtInterfaceValidPolls=1.0,Service=\"UBB-P\",CircuitID=\"PQR/ABC/IA-000000\",CountryCode=\"SG\",UsageIdentifier=\"PQR/ABC/IA-000000\",Customer=\"Test customer\",SubInterfaceDescription=\"PW-Ether4.2\",GMTTimeStamp=2020-02-16 21:45:00+00:00,tz=\"Asia/Singapore\" 1581918300': invalid number\nunable to parse
```

I thought it might be time precision issue, I have tried all combinations in time_precision paramter of write_points. But nothing helps !

I have tried using "json" protocol, with that I get 204 ret code, but measurement is not created in db.

Can someone please give a clue ?

Regards,
-Manish